# How to get Firebase server timestamp?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli

I want to save date to the firebase server with server generated timestamp using Firebase module 'Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP'.

How can I configure to import Firebase as module in angular2 project.

I am using Angular2, angular-cli, angularFire2 etc. Following are the configuration settings.

```
System-config.ts
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
    firebase: 'vendor/firebase/lib/firebase-web.js',
    angularfire2: ' vendor/angularfire2'
};
/** User packages configuration.*/
const packages: any = {
      angularfire2: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: 'angularfire2.js'
      }
};
```

**angular-cli-build.js**

```
/* global require, module */
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',

      // below are the AngularFire entries
      'angularfire2/**/*.js',
      'firebase/lib/*.js'      
    ]
  });
};
```

Comment: did you solve this? I've seen https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/211 but not sure how to implement. If you have a solution could you post it please?

Comment: I solved the problem by switching to firebase 3 API. Actually I had asked that question to the developers and they pointed me to the latest API. Which firebase version u using?

Comment: I'm not sure as I'm still just getting my head around all of this angular/firebase stuff but this is from package.json: "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.0"

Comment: And I have "firebase": "^2.4.2",

Comment: Take a look at Todo app example built with Angular2 and AngularFire2 https://github.com/r-park/todo-angular2-firebase. After setting up u will see the timestamps are saved in firebase database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Angularfire2, Angular 2, and angular-cli, the following solution worked for me.

First, make sure to import firebase with:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Next, use the old way of getting the timestamp, for example:

```
let dateNow = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
console.log(dateNow);
```

Finally, open src/typings.d.ts and add:

```
declare namespace firebase.database.ServerValue {
  let TIMESTAMP: any;
}
```

The last part was what did the trick for me and was different from most solutions floating around that aren't using the OPs specific setup.

Comment: Its still returning an object , and i dont have `src/typings.d.ts` file in my app  , I am using angular 2 as well. Any Idea

Answer (score 2):

For bypass way, you can use `{'.sv': 'timestamp'}`

```
db.object('path').set({ timestamp: {'.sv': 'timestamp'}}) // angular
```

`firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` == `{'.sv': 'timestamp'}`

Comment: This solution avoids to import firebase into the component in Angular.